# How to call dialog fragment in onClicklistener from recycler adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler adapter that displays in the fragment. When I click on the item, I want that open dialog fragment. getSupportFragmentmanager is do not call he is highlighted in red. How to open a dialog fragment. Help me please maybe, I have the wrong logic for that.

```
public class TehcnikMyProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TehcnikMyProfileAdapter.RequestFriendViewHolder> {

List<Vehicles> listVehicles = Collections.emptyList();
Context context;

public TehcnikMyProfileAdapter(List<Vehicles> list, Context context) {
    this.listVehicles = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RequestFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_technik, parent, false);
    return new RequestFriendViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RequestFriendViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.titleFirm.setText(listVehicles.get(position).getFirmName());
    holder.titleModel.setText(listVehicles.get(position).getModelName());


    holder.titleYear.setText(String.valueOf(listVehicles.get(position).getYear()));
//        holder.countPhoto.setText(String.valueOf(listVehicles.get(position).getPhotos().size()));
        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, FriendProfileActivity.class);
              //  myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              //  myIntent.putExtra("id", mUserList.get(position).getId());
            //    context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        };
        holder.imgvMooreOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
                GarageOptionDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new GarageOptionDialogFragment();
                myDialogFragment.show(manager, "dialog");
            }
        });
        holder.cv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
        return listVehicles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code/logic which you have written ?

Comment: My code in adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCombatActivity

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: not helped when click item have next error: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content

Answer (score 0):

For **AppCompatActivity** use this:

```
FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

EventRegFragmentDialog eventRegFragment= new EventRegFragmentDialog();

  eventRegFragment.show(manager, "Edit Fragment");
```

And please import this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Answer (score 0):

After my big journey in Android Development, I can definitely say that It's better not to call anything directly from the adapter. You must pass the interface(listeners) to the adapter and call what you need in fragment/activity. So it will look like this:
Firstly let's create an interface in the adapter(you can create an interface whenever you want and according to your project architecture.)

```
interface OnItemClick{
              void onItemClick();
    }

public class TehcnikMyProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TehcnikMyProfileAdapter.RequestFriendViewHolder> {

private List<Vehicles> listVehicles = Collections.emptyList();
private Context context;
private OnItemClick clickListener;

public TehcnikMyProfileAdapter(List<Vehicles> list, Context context, OnItemClick clickListener) {
    this.listVehicles = list;
    this.context = context;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@Override
public RequestFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_technik, parent, false);
    return new RequestFriendViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RequestFriendViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.titleFirm.setText(listVehicles.get(position).getFirmName());
    holder.titleModel.setText(listVehicles.get(position).getModelName());


    holder.titleYear.setText(String.valueOf(listVehicles.get(position).getYear()));
//        holder.countPhoto.setText(String.valueOf(listVehicles.get(position).getPhotos().size()));
        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, FriendProfileActivity.class);
              //  myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              //  myIntent.putExtra("id", mUserList.get(position).getId());
            //    context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        };
        holder.imgvMooreOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //get this callback in your Activity/Fragment
            this.clickListener.onItemClick
//Move this logic into Activity/Fragment
>                 FragmentManager manager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
>                 GarageOptionDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new GarageOptionDialogFragment();
>                 myDialogFragment.show(manager, "dialog");

            }
        });
        holder.cv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
        return listVehicles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```